# Bash variable command

Tags: bash, variables, rsync

Here is the simplified bit of my code that's causing problems:

```
#!/bin/bash

SRC=${BASH_ARGV[1]}
DEST=${BASH_ARGV[0]}

err=""
RSYNC="rsync -Dgoptrl --exclude 'backup-info'"

err=`$RSYNC "$SRC" "$DEST" 2>&1 | xargs -0`;
#err=`rsync -Dgoptrl --exclude 'backup-info' "$SRC" "$DEST" 2>&1 | xargs -0`;
```

rsync copies everything but directories with the name backup-info do not get excluded. The last line however does work (i.e it does exclude backup-info). They both seem the same to me, so confused as to why one works and the other doesn't.

Thanks,
Ash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[BASH FAQ #50: "I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Put the command in an array, and execute the array.

```
RSYNC=(rsync -Dgoptrl --exclude 'backup-info')
err=`"${RSYNC[@]}" "$SRC" "$DEST" 2>&1 | xargs -0`;
```

Comment: Wow, that was a quick response! Thanks! This works for me but despite reading the article you mentioned, I'm still confused. Okay, I get single quotes being literal and not syntactical, but 'backup-info' does not contain a space so why should WordSplitting split it up?

Comment: @Ash Word splitting would not split `backup-info`, but it would split `backup info`. What's happening in your original code is that the single quotes are treated literally (because they're inside double quotes), so that `rsync` sees the arguments `--exclude` `'backup-info'`. If you had a file called `'backup-info'` it would be excluded.